# is navigator.buildID in FireFox browser is unique per OS

Tags: firefox, build

From documentation:
buildID is the build identifier of the application as a string. The build ID is in form YYYYMMDDHH

When I run `navigator.buildID` in my browser I get `"20180323154952"`, so I assume that they added minutes, seconds and milliseconds to the buildID.

What I don't understand is if this buildID is unique per OS? Meaning that if there is some buildID X in FireFox that were built for Windows, ill never find same buildID in FireFox that were built for Linux, even if they  share same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that, while it *can* happen for `buildID` to be different across OSs, that's not enforced anywhere. For example, here's a list of [build ids](https://hg.mozilla.org/build/tools/file/tip/release/patcher-configs/mozRelease-branch-patcher2.cfg) for all the Firefox Release builds, all OSs. For version 59.0.2, the entry looks like that:

```
        <59.0.2>
            checksumsurl   http://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/candidates/59.0.2-candidates/build1/%platform%/%locale%/firefox-59.0.2.checksums
            completemarurl   http://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/candidates/59.0.2-candidates/build1/update/%platform%/%locale%/firefox-59.0.2.complete.mar
            <exceptions>
                ja   linux-i686, linux-x86_64, win32, win64
                ja-JP-mac   mac
            </exceptions>
            extension-version   59.0.2
            locales   ach af an ar as ast az be bg bn-BD bn-IN br bs ca cak cs cy da de dsb el en-GB en-US en-ZA eo es-AR es-CL es-ES es-MX et eu fa ff fi fr fy-NL ga-IE gd gl gn gu-IN he hi-IN hr hsb hu hy-AM ia id is it ja ja-JP-mac ka kab kk km kn ko lij lt lv mai mk ml mr ms my nb-NO ne-NP nl nn-NO or pa-IN pl pt-BR pt-PT rm ro ru si sk sl son sq sr sv-SE ta te th tr uk ur uz vi xh zh-CN zh-TW
            <platforms>
                linux-i686   20180323154952
                linux-x86_64   20180323154952
                mac   20180323154952
                win32   20180323154952
                win64   20180323154952
            </platforms>
        </59.0.2>
```

As you can see under `<platforms>`, the build id is the same for *mac*, *win32*, *win64* and *linux* for this version of Firefox Release.